# Which API to use for Dropbox files manipulation

Tags: c#, winforms, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing a winform application.I want to provide support for Dropbox in my application. Since my application is .net 3.5 based. I can't use the Dropbox SDK. So, I will be using the rest API. But there are two sets of Dropbox API V1 and V2 for Dropbox. So, are V2 API's stable enough, so that I develop my application using them or should I use the V1 API's.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question is not that easy since you have to factor in a number of considerations you do not provide information on. Skill level, product time constraints etc all play a role here.

That being said, I have used API V2 but there are some teething issues at times and support / updates are not always lighting quick. API V1 on the other hand have plenty of examples and community support is readily accessible. So my answer would be to use V1 if you favor stability and support over being on the latest release. Even if you use V1 I dont believe you have to fear the API being depreciated very soon, Dropbox has in the past given plenty of notice before they drop support for a API version.

Comment: They may give plenty of notice for dropping a API but they will likely drop it eventually, so that is time you will need to account for when you are planning the costs of using V1 or V2. They will likely drop V2 eventually too but you will likely get two or three more years life out of it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain As mentioned at the start, VK has to consider his own situation and constraints. I agree that V2 will also be dropped somewhere in the future, that is the way technology evolves. However, as mentioned V2 can still be buggy. Thus VK might spend more time developing the app initially on V2 that what he would have on V1. If the app is a once off or if time to market is critical or even if VK requires a large number of examples to build his app, V1 in my opinion would be the better choice. The point is, there is more than just on criterion to base the decision on.